# AutoHotKey doesn't start program out of Visual Studio Code + AutoHotkey Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, autohotkey

I want to make a script with Visual Studio Code and AHK that starts a certain program (automatically connect to a VPN ==> FortiClient).

If I double click directly on the script only containing that specific ahk run command in Windows Explorer, the client starts as desired. From Visual Studio code nothing happens.

I tried:

> run, %programfiles%\Fortinet\FortiClient\FortiClient.exe

==> Works with double click from Windows explorer. Running from VS Code: nothing.

> run, C:\Program Files\Fortinet\FortiClient\FortiClient.exe

==> Works with double click from Windows explorer. Running from VS Code: nothing.

I made a link to the exe an put that to a folder without a blank character in the directory name:

> run, C:\Software_Checkout\AHK\FortiClient_Verknuepfung.lnk

==> Works with double click from Windows explorer. Running from VS Code: nothing.

What can be the reason for this?

Comment: Other commands like msgbox or send work from VS Code. Just the run command is not working (so far).

Comment: Is the script running?

Comment: Yes, the script runs and returns without error. But the run command is just doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce, so I'll give a dumb suggestion. Complete shot in the dark, but make sure you're not starting VS Code from under WSL. I've made that mistake in the past, the head scratches were plentiful. Other than that, I don't know what could be the issue. Maybe a faulty debugger?

Example script that works for me from VS Code, with several debuggers:

```
ProgramFilesX86 := A_ProgramFiles . (A_PtrSize=8 ? " (x86)" : "")
run %ProgramFilesX86%\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).